# Disabling a button in Netbeans GUI until correct password is put into the password field

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, passwords

I'm very new at coding, and I want a swing button in the netbeans GUI to stay disabled until the correct password is entered to a password field. I have already created the password field, and given it a correct password.

If you can keep it simple it would be appreciated, as I'm very new to programming in general.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `setEnabled` property,

```
button.setEnabled(true);
```

you can set it to `false` initially , upon validating make it `true` .

```
if (text.equals("password"))
   button.setEnabled(false);
```

As [`#setEnabled(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setEnabled(boolean)),

> Enables or disables this component, depending on the value of the parameter b. An enabled component can respond to user input and generate events. Components are enabled initially by default.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense, I added it and it compiled with no errors.. But- It doesn't do anything in the GUI. The button is still enabled, and the password field doesn't let me know whether the admitted password is true or false.
I can add pictures if needed

Comment: @SteenDanielHunter sorry it is vice versa . check to my updated answer and let me know for your question

Answer (score 0):

You should first set the button to **setEnabled(false)** and then make a new method, to check if the password in the field is correct such as this:

```
public void check()
{
    boolean c = true;
    while(c){
        if(pf.getText().equals(correct_password)) c = false;
    }
    button.setEnabled(true);
}
```

And you should run this method in a new Thread, so that it does not freeze your GUI.

When the password will be correct, then it will be enabled.

**P.S.** *I know that using **getText** for a Password Field is deprecated by **getPassword()**, but for the sake of simplicity, I have used **getText()** here.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jButton1.setEnabled(false)
String text = jTextField.getText();
```

Into Thread

```
if (text.contains("password"))
jButton1.setEnabled(true);
```

put the If statement code in thread and set the thread delay to 2sec (2000ms)